# React - Context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a problem with React - Context. 
For now I just want to pass the value'hello' but unfortunately it does not find the value.

This is my Context:

```
import React from 'react';

const MovieContext = React.createContext();

class MovieProvider extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state={

        };
    };

    render() { 
        return ( 
            <MovieContext.Provider value={'hello'}>
                {this.props.children}
            </MovieContext.Provider>
         );
    }
}

export {MovieProvider,  MovieContext};
```

Here is my Layout which collects my Provider:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import { MovieProvider } from './context';



class Layout extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(

            <MovieProvider>
                <>
                    <Header/>
                    {this.props.children} 
                </>

            </MovieProvider>


        )
    }   
}

export default Layout;
```

And here is my index which should display 'hello':

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import {MovieContext} from '../components/context';

class Index extends React.Component{

    static contextType = MovieContext

    render(){

        const value = this.context;
        console.log(value)
        return(

            <div>
                <Layout>
                    {value}
                    <h1>Home Page</h1>
                </Layout>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Index;
```

I tried to put the provider in my Index Component but unfortunately it doesn't work either. Mostly I followed the doc and I thought I had done everything well haha

Comment: its easier with hooks, just fyi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` is not valid in `Index` component, as according to Context API, you have to use `Context.Consumer` in any `Context.Provider`'s child in order to reference the context's value.

> When React renders a component that subscribes to this Context object it will read the current context value from the closest matching Provider above it in the tree. - [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#api)

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MovieProvider>
        <MovieContext.Consumer>
          {value => (
            <>
              {value}
              <h1>Home Page</h1>
            </>
          )}
        </MovieContext.Consumer>
      </MovieProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit elastic-cannon-ffwio]

Comment: I saw a video where the person doesn't immediately use the Consumer and it worked, weird.
Thanks again :)

Comment: You **don't have to** use `Consumer` **immediately**, you can use it in any child (depth) within the provider tree as mentioned

Comment: Ok, Thank you :)